# innerHTML and silently decoded quotes

Tags: javascript, json, innerhtml

THE SETUP:

On the page, in a hidden div, is a well-formed JSON object.

As part of this object, some of the values are HTML, and in this HTML, double-quotes are HTML-encoded, like so: `"addtionalInfo": "If you need more help, please visit &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;"`

Later on the page, I'm trying to write JS that will read this object in so other cool things can be done.

THE PROBLEM:
innerHTML seems to be implicitly decoding the quotes, which means JSON.parse() (and similar jQuery options) fail because the syntax bonks.  I can't replace() the quotes since they're all over the place in proper JSONy ways.

AN EXAMPLE:

```
<span class="hiddenField" id="TheJSONObject">


 { "thing" : "thingvalue", "badthing" : "a &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;&gt;link!&lt;/a&gt;", "lastthing" : "lastthingvalue" }


</span>

<script>
var newobj = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("TheJSONObject").innerHTML.trim());
alert(newobj.thing);
```

PROOF FROM THE CONSOLE (CHROME):

```
console.log(document.getElementById("TheJSONObject").innerHTML) 


 { "thing" : "thingvalue", "badthing" : "a &lt;a href="http://www.google.com"&gt;link!&lt;/a&gt;", "lastthing" : "lastthingvalue" }
```

THE QUESTION:
Is there any way to get the actual raw innerHTML without JS trying to do me a kindness like this so that JSON.parse() will work?

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  The issue isn't the URL-encoding but rather the HTML-encoding; the &quot;s going away when I try to put them in a box with innrHTML.  Could you explain how the URI functions would help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s completely impossible. You have a `<span>`, not a `<script>` or anything else that’s treated as literal text, so there’s no difference between a `&quot;` and a `"`. You need to encode it properly to begin with; that probably means HTML-encoding the JSON-encoded object containing the HTML-encoded value for output as HTML.

If you’re not able to modify that output, the closest you can get will probably be to make a (XHR) request and parse it out manually with the entities intact.

Comment: Why is &quot; (seemingly) the only entity this happens with then?  (Not that I doubt your answer, I'm just curious if you know why it's only this encoding compared to all the others)

Comment: @steegness: It’s not necessary to escape quotation marks outside of quoted attribute values, so the browser doesn’t escape them when reconstructing `innerHTML`.